# ASMX WebService CacheDuration, Is it Session or Application Level?

Tags: c#, web-services, caching, asmx

I am attempting to cache the output of a WebMethod in my WebService. The Method I am trying to cache returns Data that will likely only change once every few months at most, so I would like to cache that output to cut down on load time. I have been looking at the WebMethod CacheDuration property, but caching the output will not help me at all if CacheDuration is only Session level. Does anyone know whether CacheDuration will work on the Application Level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no explicit answer to that BUT on MSDN (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.cacheduration%28v=VS.100%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) it indictates that caching depends on "unique parameter sets" and not on the session... so I assume it is application level - with the samples provided at those links you could test that easily...

Another option worth exploring regarding caching is to explicitly use the [`Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) class - this gives full control over all aspects of caching although is less "transparent" than the method you describe... for example you can set duration how long the cached item stays "valid", you can provide a callback which is called when an item is about to be discarded etc.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a reference that definitively says it's one or the other, but I would *assume* it's applied at the Application level if only because applying it at the Session level doesn't make sense e.g. it wouldn't help your scalability.

Comment: I agree that it would only make sense if it applied at the Application Level, but I can't find anything that confirms or denies this assumption. Hence the appeal to the Programming Gods :)